# Pattern recognition algorithms for strings with weighted filters?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition

Are there pattern recognition algorithms where I can specify the weight of matching or missing certain parameters? For example, suppose I have 3 strings:

```
str1 = Samsung 11.6" 64GB Slate PC Tablet with Wi-Fi - Black  
str2 = Samsung Series 7 XE700T1A-A05US 11.6-Inch Slate (64 GB, Win 7 Pro)
str3 = Samsung Series 7 XE700T1A-A03US 11.6-Inch Slate (128 GB SSD, Win 7 HP)
```

I would like to match str2 to str1 since they have equal GB, even though conventional string distance would say str2 is closer to str3. In reality, I would hope for anything that can handle a large number of parameters with different weights.

Any pointers to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: But "64\s+GB" only in str1 and str2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create **dictionary** of named entities, e.g. "Samsung", "Inch", "Wi-Fi", etc.
2. Create set of **rules** to extract features, e.g. `{Number}{Space}?"GB"` for gigabytes or `{TradeMark}{Space}"Series"{Space}{Number}` for trademark and series.
3. Create **feature vector**, setting known attributes to corresponding values and unknown attributes to something like "NA" (Not Available).
4. Measure **distance between items** (represented as feature vectors), not strings.

Note: to easier work with dictionaries and rules consider using [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) framework. To measure distance between 2 vectors you may use [cosine distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

Answer (score 2):

What you likely want to do is develop a parser that extracts relevant information from the String and then weights it, instead of operating on the string itself.

This could consist of generating a set of regular expressions that extract the tidbits you want (these are known as 'features'. e.g.,GB) or using a more complex parsing or NLP techniques.  Then you would develop a weight function yourself or use some sort of [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering) (for similarity) or [classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_%28mathematics%29) (for putting things into categories)

For your simple example, generating a regex that looks like `GB [0-9]+` should be sufficient to do the comparison.